# Choosing a string primary key vs using a join table with corresponding integer id

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a large sensor data count table say SENSORS_COUNT with a string SID referring to another table SENSOR_DEFINITIONS with the same primary key SID. As there are millions of data points, the index on string primary key becomes 1) bloated 2) slow. The total number of sensors is pretty small (< 2000).

I can think about 3 different ways of making the queries faster:

1. Using a join table which translates the string key into a corresponding integer key and refer that with joins in all queries
2. Load the string/integer translation as a hash in program memory and refer that within the code
3. Use index on  string primary id (which would be slower than integer though)

I'm trying to build a system for a variety of sensors which may have different types of string ids (but same schema). What would be the best recommendation to go about it?

EDIT 1: This is the schema. And yes (thanks for the correction), in SENSORS_COUNT table, SID is not a primary key

```
TABLE: SENSOR_DEFINITIONS (2000 records)
SID : VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY
SNAME: VARCHAR(50)

TABLE: SENSORS_COUNT (N million records)
SID: VARCHAR(20)
DATETIME: TIMESTAMP
VALUE: INTEGER
```

Comment: How do you know it is slower?  Have you run any performance benchmarks?

Comment: Thanks for correcting. It is not slower, but slow. I'm trying to find a way to make faster than what they currently are. Also the question is more oriented towards what are the best practises DB admins use. Or recommendation of resources that a non-DBA developer can use.

Comment: Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Note: if `SID` is a primary key for `SENSORS_COUNT`and there are only 2000 different values for SID, there cannot be more than 2000 records in sensor_count. Please show the real definitions of the tables.

Comment: The exact definition of "string" here will have a big impact on performance, e.g. `CHAR(4) CHARACTER SET latin1` is large enough for 2000 sensor identifiers in a single case and should be about as efficient as 32-bit integers. `VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` will be less efficient.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for correcting. I have updated question above. -e4c5 I'll looking for generic best practises in such situations rather than a particular query. E.g. even making an inner join sum query is pretty slow when it reaches 10's of millions of count points. -reaanb You are correct. However I was wondering what experienced database admins do in such scenario - use string key indexed or use joins.

Comment: Sorry, your *schema* is nonsense. What are the primary keys? what is the foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

For "large" tables, normalization becomes more important.  Especially when the table is too big to be cached.

So, I agree with the choice of using a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, 0..64K) for the 2000 sensor names, not a `VARCHAR(...)`.

Without seeing (1) the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and (2) some critical `SELECTs`, it is hard to give further advice.

Probably, a "composite" `PRIMARY KEY` would be better than an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  It might be `(sensor_id, datetime)`, but it would help to see the selects first.

Do *not* have two tables with the same schema (without a good reason).

Comment: What does using a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` have to do with normalization?

Comment: Normalization is where you build a table of strings mapped to integers, then use the integers in the big table(s).  I am recommending that particular variant of "integer" as being optimal for your purpose.

Comment: Nonsense. Normalization in the context of databases refers to decomposing relations to uniquely and distinctly represent dependencies. Introducing surrogate keys can sometimes be used in the process of normalization, but just introducing a surrogate key as a compact representation of another domain doesn't have anything to do with normalization.

Comment: @reaanb - Is there a technical name for such?

Comment: I'm not aware of an established term for it. I might call it domain indexing if I had to coin one.

Comment: Choosing integer keys has absolutely nothing to do with normalization.